# Group Epimorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-numbers, rational-numbers, group-homomorphism

Is there a group epimorphism $f$ from $(\mathbb{R},+)$ to $(\mathbb{Q},+)$?
Surely $f(0)$ goes to $0$, but my problem is where to send elements of $\mathbb{R}\smallsetminus\mathbb{Q}$.